# How represent message for Elgamal EC?

Tags: elliptic-curve, elgamal

I am working on my project that uses elgamal elliptic curve.
I know when the elgamal ec encrypt by following steps

1. Represent the message m as a point M in E(Fp).
2. Select k ∈R [1,n−1].
3. Compute C1 = kP.
4. Compute C2 = M +kQ.
5. Return(C1,C2).
   Where Q is the intended recipient’s public key, P is base point.
   My qusetion at number one. how represent m as a point. Is point represent one character or represent group of characters.

Answer (score 1):

There's no obvious way to attach m to points in E(Fp). However, you can use variant algorithm of ElGamal such as Menezes-Vanstone Elliptic curve cryptosystem to encode a message 
in a point, a good reference [here(P.31)](http://www.ee.tamu.edu/~reddy/ee689_04/pres_joel_nitesh.pdf).

As for java code, I suggest you do some work, and post another question on SO when you encounter a problem you really can't solve by yourself.

Comment: Mr ChiaraHsieh Thank you for your answer

Comment: I've got just wondered algorithm Menezes-Vanstone Elliptic Curve
Cryptosystem What is the intent of this phrase 
The ciphertext of a message m = (m1, m2) ∈ Zp * × Zp * 

What is meant by Zp*×Zp* 

Is that the message is within the domain finite field Zp must be a message within the period from 1 to 10.

Comment: It means m1 and m2 are both elements of Zp*, which could be from 1 to p-1

Comment: Just I ask about Menezes-Vanstone Elliptic curve cryptosystem. Howcan encode a message while C1= M1 * k1, C2= K2 * M2. I now M1 and M2 here is message. Is M1, M2 represent on one character or more that. Or represent many characters binay size less than P.